# React Hook and Context not persisting on redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am still navigating React hooks and contexts and have been attempting to use both to store user information for further usage in other portions of my app after successful authentication from an axios request. With my code that follows, I successfully set the state used in the context, but when the state is accessed following a redirect that occurs directly after setting the value, it comes back as undefined and I'm not sure what is preventing the value from being stored.

**Provided is my context and hook (AppSession.js):**

```
    import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'
    
    export const SessionContext = createContext(null);
    
    const AppSession = ({ children }) => {
        const [user, setUser] = useState()
    
        if (user){
            console.log("useState: Authenticated")
            console.log(user)
        } else {
            console.log("useState: Not authenticated")
            console.log(user)
        }
    
        return (
            <SessionContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
                {children}
            </SessionContext.Provider>
        )
    
    }
    
    export const getUserState = () => {
        const { user } = useContext(SessionContext)
        return user;
    }
    
    export const updateUserState = () => {
        const { setUser } = useContext(SessionContext)
        
        return (user) => {
            setUser(user);
        }
    }
    
    export default AppSession;

**Provided is the axios request and console logs upon successful response (login.js):**

    axios.post(
        '/api/auth/signin/',
        { email, password },
        {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            withCredentials: true
        }).then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data) // {authenticated: true, user_id: "071c7b80-6b4d-462c-8c4a-4fa613a7e8b6", user_email: "Alysson_Runolfsdottir@yahoo.com"}
          const data = res.data; //
          console.log("updateUserState")
          setUser(data)
        }).then(()=> {
          return window.location = '/app/profile/'
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })

    // Console.logs
    { authenticated: true, user_id: "071c7b80-6b4d-462c-8c4a-4fa613a7e8b6", user_email: "Alysson_Runolfsdottir@yahoo.com" } // login.js
    updateUserState // login.js
    useState: Authenticated // AppSession.js
{ authenticated: true, user_id: "071c7b80-6b4d-462c-8c4a-4fa613a7e8b6", user_email: "Alysson_Runolfsdottir@yahoo.com" } // AppSession.js
```

**Then the code for `profile.js` which is the result of redirect to `/app/profile` with console logs:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { getUserState }  from '../../contexts/AppSession'
import Layout from '../../components/Universal/Layout'

export default function Profile(props) {
  const checkUser = getUserState()
  console.log(checkUser)
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <Layout 
      title="Signin"
      description="TEST"
      >
      <h1>Protected Page</h1>
      <p>You can view this page because you are signed in.</p>
      <br />
      <b>Check User: {checkUser}</b>
    </Layout>
  )
}

// Console.logs
useState: Not authenticated // AppSession.js
undefined // AppSession.js (console.log(user))
undefied // profile.js (console.log(checkUser))
```

As you can see the storage is short-lives as the subsuquent page that loads upon redirect access the user state and it is `undefined`. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: A redirect is a page load. A page load means anything not in persistent storage (e.g., local storage, cookies, whatever) goes away, just like with any web page. That's why there's things like react-router/etc. that don't leave the page--they're called single-page apps for a reason :)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense :) I should find the NextJS equivalent of the react-router approach you mentioned.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction